# how to add a rule condition for email in javascript validation

Tags: javascript, php, validation, email

i have an email input field in my form. Validations are done by using javascript. There is no problem with email validation, it works correctly. but i want to check an additional condition for email,  if anyone have no email he/she can type "NO" in field. That is "NO" or valid email is allowable only. pls help me. my current rules for email is

```
                    My_email: {  
                    required: true,
                    email:true,                                                       
                },
```

Comment: Don't do it - make email optional and require that if it is entered it is a valid email address.  You may also have a checkbox that people can use to indicate they would like to receive email.

Comment: Client side validations **aren't reliable**, use server side validation.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to enter `NO` as an option versus an email address, please include how you're validating that field.

Comment: @PedroLobito using client side validation does not preclude server side validation - IMO it's still valuable for instant feedback without roundtrip to server.

Answer (score 0):

For javascript validation , if using jquery take a look at jquery validate

http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

simple example

create rules

```
 var loginValidationConfig = {                    
    wrapper: "div",
    rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            password: {
                required: "<i class='sprite-attentionw_error_icon'></i>The username or password you entered is incorrect.<br />Please try again.",                    
            },
            email: {
                required: "<i class='sprite-attentionw_error_icon'></i>The username or password you entered is incorrect.<br />Please try again.",                    
                email: "<i class='sprite-attentionw_error_icon'></i>The username or password you entered is incorrect.<br />Please try again."
            }
        }
}
```

then on the form you do

```
 $(this).validate(loginValidationConfig);
```

That will print the validation next to the fields
Youll need to read at least part of the documentation anyways

Comment: i tried this    `fathers_email: {  
                        required: true,
                        checkMail:true,                                                       
                    }                                                                                                                                                                                         `

Comment: `var checkMail = function IsEmail(email) {
                var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$+no+NO/;
                return regex.test(email);
            }`

Comment: my email validation is already working , now i want to allow another condition for email

Comment: i tried another code  `jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkMail", function(value, element) {  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/.test(value);
            }, "valid email please.");`

Comment: can i add ''no '' to this expression

Answer (score 0):

If your function to validate the email address is the one given in the comment to Sudakatux's answer

```
var checkMail = function IsEmail(email) { 
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]2,4})+$+no+NO/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

it makes me wonder that it works at all to validate email addresses (e.g.: the ending "museum" has a tad bit more letters in it than the mere four you assume) but that could be the problem of C&P, of course, together with the lack of formating abilities for the comments, so I take it as a given that it works.

As already mentioned: you do not validate email-addresses client-side besides some rudimentary checks, e.g.: has it an @-sign in it and some dots and do the rest by sending *the* email (not just a test-email!) and see if it bounces. There are some well tested regular expressions for that type of checks to be found somewhere on the net but also somewhere here.

Going with the most simple approach

```
var checkMail = function (email) { 
  var regex = /^.+@[^@]+?\.[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

Check with

```
var email1 = "a.s@g.a"; // correct but does not exist
var email2 = "a@g";
var email3 = "ag.de";
var email4 = "ag.@.d@e";
var email5 = "a@g@d.de";

console.log("1 " + checkMail(email1));
console.log("2 " + checkMail(email2));
console.log("3 " + checkMail(email3));
console.log("4 " + checkMail(email4));
console.log("5 " + checkMail(email5));
```

But that's not what you want, you want to check for more than one value and do something different depending on that value. You can check with a regex that either value exists but you do not know which one. You need two regular expressions for that.

Assuming you want "NO" (upper case "N" and upper case "O")

```
var checkMail = function (email) { 
  var regexEmail = /^.+@[^@]+?\.[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  var regexNO = /^NO$/;
  if(!regexEmail.test(email)){
    if(!regexNO.test(email)){
      return -1; // nothing in it
    }
    return 1; // Intentionally no email address given
  }
  return 2; // something vaguely resembling an email given
}
```

You can use it in something like:

```
var valueEmailField = checkMail(email)
if(valueEmailField > 0){
  if(valueEmailField == 1){
    // User said "NO", act accordingly
  }
  // user gave something email-like, act accordingly
}
else {
  // email field empty, act accordingly
}
```

From a users point of view it is better to use a check-box instead of text to enter. A check-box is much less error-prone. Yes, ti is possible to mistype a two letter word.

As an opt-in for example:

[ ] I want your answer emailed, please use the following address to do so:
    |___________________________| email address

Well, maybe a bit more elegant than that ;-)

Just test the check-box first and if the box is checked, test the entry for validity.